# STRUTS2 and AJAX - Select the country, populate the States

Tags: ajax, struts2

I want to show the states after selecting the country.

JSP

```
       <s:select label="COUNTRY" name="summaryData.addressCountry" id="addForm_countryCode" 
                                      list="loyaltyCountryMap" tabindex="" headerKey="US" headerValue="United States"
                                      listKey="key" listValue="value.countryName" 
                                      onchange="getStateList('#addForm_countryCode')">

       </s:select> 

<s:select label="STATE" name="summaryData.addressCityCode" headerValue="-Select-" headerKey="-Select-" list="stateList" required="true" cssClass="storedPaymentInput_size1 required" id="stateList"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  function getStateList() {
        var countryCode = $('#addForm_countryCode").val(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxStateList',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { countryCode : countryCode},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#stateList').html( data );
            }
        });
    }
```

STRUTS.XML

```
     <action name="ajaxStateList" class="actions.AjaxStateList">
       <result name="success"/>
 </action>
```

ACTION CLASS

```
 private List<String> stateList;

    private String countryCode;

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public List<String> getStateList() {
        return stateList;
    }

    public void setStateList(List<String> stateList) {
        this.stateList = stateList;
    }

    public String execute() {

        LoyaltyStateProvinces.getInstance();

        stateList = StateProvinces.getAllStateProvinceByCountryCode(countryCode);

        for(StateProvince state: states){
            stateList.add(state.getStateProvinceCode());
        }


        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

How can I make it work using AJAX+Struts2?

Comment: +1 simply for trying with jQuery and not using those wretched ajax tag libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [struts2-json-plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin). Have your actions return a json result type (via this plugin). Your action class can remain largely unmodified.

Once you have created and tested that your action returns JSON (just enter the url in your browser). Then you need some javaScript. I see you are using jQuerys $.ajax method... I prefer the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which does the same but assumes the data in a json format.

Here is some js from my own code:

```
            function punch(){
                $.getJSON("<s:url namespace="/timeclock/json" action="punch"/>",
                {
                    badge: $("#input_badge").val()
                },
                function(data) {
                    $("#input_badge").val("");
                    $("#emp_name").text(data.name);
                    $("#emp_time").text(data.punch);
                    $("#notification").fadeIn("slow", hide);
                });
                return false;
            }
```

You'll notice three parameters: Fist being the url for the call which is always best constructed with the sturts2 url tag. Second being the parameters being sent to the action, in this case "badge" is set to what ever was in the text field with the id of "input_badge" and then sent to the server. Finally the function which is called when the call back succeeds, you can see parameters such as "name", "punch" are returned.